# creating my own module and types doesnt work as expected

Tags: list, haskell, types, module, tuples

I'm trying to make a haskell program with modules and create my own types to simulate a election: So far I have this:

```
module Election
( nactionCreate
,  getState
, addVotesToState
, nactionAddVotes
, stateWinner
, electionWinner
) where

-- Types Created
data Candidate = A | B deriving (Eq, Show)

type State = (String, Int, Int, Int) --deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

name :: State -> String
name (name, _, _, _) = name

representativesNumber :: state -> Int
representativesNumber (_, representativesNumber, _, _,) = representativesNumber

aVotes :: State -> Int
aVotes (_, _, aVotes, _) = aVotes

bVotes :: State -> Int
bVotes (_, _, _, bVotes) = bVotes

type Naction = [State]

-- Create a Naction From a tuples List for each State at the beginning of Election. In the beginnig each candidate has 0 votes
nactionCreate:: [(String,Int)] -> Naction
nactionCreate ((n,r):xs) = [State | name <- n, representativeNumber<-r, 0, 0]

-- Return the State with the name equal to the String. Don't exists states with equals name
getState :: Naction -> String -> State
getState [] _ = null
getState ((n,_,_,_):xs) s =
    | n == s = State
    | otherwise = getState xs s


-- TODO 
addVotesToState :: State -> Int -> Int -> State

-- TODO
nactionAddVotes :: Naction -> [(String, Int, Int)] -> Naction

-- TODO
stateWinner :: State -> Candidate

-- TODO
electionWinner :: Naction -> Candidate
```

but i'm having a hard time knowing how to manipulate mas data/types. Like for example in `nactionCreate` it's suppose to work like:

```
> naction0 =createNaction [("North",4), ("Central",6), ("West",3)]
```

and then I should could be able to do:

```
> north0 = getState naction0 "North"
> representativesNumber north0
4
> aVotes north0
0
> bVotes north0
0
```

I know that the function that I already made aren't correct (I mean I suspect) but I can't understand why or how to work with... Can someone help me please?

**P.S.:** I dont wanna help with the functions I haven't tried to make yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getState` isn't actually creating a value of type `State`; you are just using the type constructor in a place where is cannot be used. You are getting an error because there is no *data constructor* named `State`. You want to return the value that had the name `n` instead.

There's also no such value as `null`. You want the return type to be `Maybe State`, using `Nothing` to signal failure and `Just` to wrap a successful match.

```
getState :: Naction -> String -> Maybe State
getState [] _ = Nothing
getState (state@(n,_,_,_):xs) s =
    | n == s = Just state
    | otherwise = getState xs s
```

Here the name `state` refers to the head of the list of `State` values as a whole, so that you don't have to capture and repeat all the values in the tuple.